# Turning a list of list of list into a single dictionary

Tags: python

How do I get a dictionary like this:

```
{'SEA': {'SFO': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 12.041594578792296, 'OAK': 6.029925372672534}, 'SFO': {'SEA': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 9.7082439194738}}
```

from something like this:

```
[['SEA', ['SFO', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 12.041594578792296, 'OAK', 6.029925372672534]], ['SFO', ['SEA', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 9.7082439194738]]]
```

Comment: Your first item is a list of list, your second codeblock is a dictionary. It is already a dictionary. Assuming you meant the reverse, I am editing your question.

Answer (score 4):

Use a nested `dictionary comprehension` with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) as:

```
l = [['SEA', ['SFO', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 12.041594578792296, 'OAK', 6.029925372672534]], ['SFO', ['SEA', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 9.7082439194738]]]
d = {v[0]:{k:v1 for k,v1 in zip(v[1][::2], v[1][1::2])} for v in l}
```

Or using a for loop like so:

```
d = {}
for v in l:
    temp_d = {}
    for k,v1 in zip(v[1][::2],v[1][1::2]):
        temp_d[k]=v1
    d[v[0]]=temp_d
```

Or:

```
d = {v[0]:dict(zip(v[1][::2],v[1][1::2])) for v in l}
```

---

```
print(d)
{'SEA': {'SFO': 6.020797289396148,
  'DEN': 12.041594578792296,
  'OAK': 6.029925372672534},
 'SFO': {'SEA': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 9.7082439194738}}
```

Comment: I would recommend giving an example using basic for loops with much larger spacing. It will greatly improve understanding and readability. Additionally, please refer documentation to the zip function and dictionary compressions.

Comment: @Modelmat for loops are slow and requires additional variables, so better to avoid them. But given an example using for loops.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. It's just easier to explain and understand, especially for the new user.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with dict comprehension,

```
In [95]: {key:dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2])) for key,values in a}
Out[95]: 
{'SEA': {'DEN': 12.041594578792296,
  'OAK': 6.029925372672534,
  'SFO': 6.020797289396148},
 'SFO': {'DEN': 9.7082439194738, 'SEA': 6.020797289396148}}
```

`zip(values[::2], values[1::2])` will create list of tuples like this,

```
[('SFO', 6.020797289396148),
  ('DEN', 12.041594578792296),
  ('OAK', 6.029925372672534)]
```

`dict(zip(values[::2], values[1::2]))` will generate a dictionary liks this,

```
{'DEN': 12.041594578792296,
  'OAK': 6.029925372672534,
  'SFO': 6.020797289396148}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way of doing it

```
d = {'SEA': {'SFO': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 12.041594578792296, 'OAK': 6.029925372672534}, 'SFO': {'SEA': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 9.7082439194738}}

l = []
for a in d.keys():
    l2 = []
    d2 = d[a]
    for b in d2.keys():
        l2.extend([b,d2[b]])
    l.extend([a,l2])
print(l)
```

You get
['SEA', ['SFO', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 12.041594578792296, 'OAK', 6.029925372672534], 'SFO', ['SEA', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 9.7082439194738]]

Answer (score 0):

```
[['SEA', ['SFO', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 12.041594578792296, 'OAK', 6.029925372672534]], ['SFO', ['SEA', 6.020797289396148, 'DEN', 9.7082439194738]]]
```

In this on showing Array of Array which means `[ '1',['a',['a1','a2','a3']] ]`
The main Arrya 0th index `['1']` is a normal value  and the another index is a Array `['a',['a1','a2','a3']]`

But In Second Case it's a JSON data

```
{'SEA': {'SFO': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 12.041594578792296, 'OAK': 6.029925372672534}, 'SFO': {'SEA': 6.020797289396148, 'DEN': 9.7082439194738}}
```

Example :

```
{ "SEA" :{'SFO':6.020797289396148}}
```

SEA -> {} - SFO -> 6.020797289396148
basically the second method contain a object of object 
the object value as a object in  that object contain the  value 6.020797289396148

> SEA.SFO using this you can get the value of this 6.020797289396148